# Updated Vagrantfile but still getting warning that my Vagrantfile is outdated

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have updated my `Vagrantfile` to this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define :ceph do |ceph|
    ceph.vm.box = "big-ceph"
    ceph.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.251.100"
    ceph.vm.hostname = "ceph"
  end

  config.vm.define :client do |client|
    client.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    client.vm.hostname = "ceph-client"
    client.vm.provision :shell, path: "setup/ceph.sh"
    client.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.251.101"
  end

end
```

but I am still getting this warning message whenever I `vagrant up` my virtual machines.

```
calvin % vagrant reload ceph && vagrant reload client
There were warnings and/or errors while loading your Vagrantfile
for the machine 'ceph'.

Your Vagrantfile was written for an earlier version of Vagrant,
and while Vagrant does the best it can to remain backwards
compatible, there are some cases where things have changed
significantly enough to warrant a message. These messages are
shown below.

Warnings:
* `config.vm.customize` calls are VirtualBox-specific. If you're
using any other provider, you'll have to use config.vm.provider in a
v2 configuration block.
```

Any idea why?

Comment: do you have virtualbox installed? if you use others, such as vmware, you need update Vagrantfile to that provider.

Comment: I have both `virtualbox` as well as `vmware` installed.  And as you can see from my `Vagrantfile`, I am not using the `config.vm.customize` call.  So I am very puzzled why I am getting this warning message?

Comment: I have no problem with your Vagrantfile, but I only install Virtualbox. Maybe add `config.vm.provider ` part will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. This 3rd party ceph box that I am using comes with its own `Vagrantfile` which overrides my `Vagrantfile` and the included box `Vagrantfile` (which is located in `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/big-ceph`) still contains

```
config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
```

Comment that out and I no longer see the annoying warning.